# Navigation between NSVIewController

Tags: macos, nsviewcontroller

I am very new to MAC OSX app development.
In my application I have three NSViewControllers, which are PracticeController, NoteController and QuestionController. I have to navigate to NoteViewController from PracticeController and QuestionController and comeback to the viewController from which NoteController has navigated.

For example: when we navigate to NoteController from PracticeController, then when we tap on back button from NoteController I have to come to PracticeController, and when we navigate to NoteController from QuestionController, then when we tap on back button from NoteController I have to come to QuestionController.

Please help me how to do this? I am badly searching for it. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

well, after a long time search, I found a open source library which ports the UIKit to MacOSX.
https://github.com/BigZaphod/Chameleon.git
But it's too complicated for me, so I wrote my own Navigation controller.

#### NSNavigationController.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@class BaseViewController;
@interface NSNavigationController : NSResponder
@property (nonatomic, strong) BaseViewController *rootViewController;

- (id)initWithRootViewController:(BaseViewController *)rootViewController;
- (NSView*)view;

- (void)pushViewController:(BaseViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated;
- (BaseViewController *)popViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated;
@end
```

#### NSNavigationController.m

```
#import "NSNavigationController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "BaseViewController.h"

@interface NSNavigationController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *viewControllerStack;
@end

@implementation NSNavigationController
- (id)initWithRootViewController:(BaseViewController *)rootViewController
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.rootViewController = rootViewController;
        self.rootViewController.navigationController = self;
        self.viewControllerStack = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:self.rootViewController, nil];
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSView*)view
{
    BaseViewController *topViewController = [self.viewControllerStack objectAtIndex:[self.viewControllerStack count] - 1];
    return topViewController.view;
}

- (void)pushViewController:(BaseViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (viewController != nil) {
        [self removeTopView];
        [self.viewControllerStack addObject:viewController];
        viewController.navigationController = self;
        [self addTopView];
    }
}

- (BaseViewController *)popViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    BaseViewController *topViewController = [self.viewControllerStack objectAtIndex:[self.viewControllerStack count] - 1];
    [self removeTopView];
    [self.viewControllerStack removeLastObject];
    [self addTopView];

    return topViewController;
}

- (void)removeTopView
{
    BaseViewController *topViewController = [self.viewControllerStack objectAtIndex:[self.viewControllerStack count] - 1];
    [topViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
}

- (void)addTopView
{
    BaseViewController *topViewController = [self.viewControllerStack objectAtIndex:[self.viewControllerStack count] - 1];
    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate*)[NSApp delegate];
    [delegate.window.contentView addSubview:topViewController.view];
}
@end
```

#### BaseViewController.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@class NSNavigationController;

@interface BaseViewController : NSViewController
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSNavigationController *navigationController;
@end
```

#### BaseViewController.m

```
#import "BaseViewController.h"

@interface BaseViewController ()

@end

@implementation BaseViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

It's the simplest NavigationController. I didn't implement the view animation. Hope it can help.

Comment: @kilik52 Thanks for posting. Just a couple comments – Usually you don't want to name a class you make with the NS prefix. The NS implies that it was made by Next Step, and this navigation controller is not. Also, you might want to actually import NSNavigationController in the BaseViewController rather than just forward declaring it, that way any BaseViewController subclass instance can access it's navigationController property.

Comment: @RagnarDanneskjöld Thank you for your comments. I think your are right.

Comment: Hi,

Great post!! I'm trying to implement this, but could not. The window in AppDelegate is not there. This might be an update done by Apple. How can I implement this using Storyboard?