# How do I get my NSViewController to go into another ViewController without leaving the window?

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsviewcontroller

I am creating an OS X app with Cocoa and Xcode. I basically have a window controller and 2 view controllers. I have a window controller that links to a view controller. That view controller is linked to another view controller through a push button that uses a show segue to show the second controller. However, it always opens it in a new window, and I want it to stay in the same window just change the view. I would like the push button to show the second controller, but stay in the current window.

I can't seem to find much about this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe the `NSNavigationController` in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18608983/navigation-between-nsviewcontroller) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the segue type to "Sheet"

Comment: Awesome! That was simple, I should have figured that out haha :-)